# Converting binary to decimal with out using a function

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, binary, decimal

I'm trying to create a binary to decimal converter, and have got stuck on the code. I have researched forums for any help, but they all seam to use functions, which can not be used within a private sub. Please can anyone give me help on a solution to this problem?

Comment: "but they all seam to use functions, which can not be used within a private sub."  What makes you think functions can not be used inside a private sub?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the positional notation method:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation

http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Binary-to-Decimal

So basically, without giving you the answer, you want to loop through binary place holders, filling up a variable as you go along. You would use an index to move from the least significant placeholder to the most.

For example :  10011011 in binary is 155 decimal.

So every place holder is a power with a base of two. Then you add the value for each one until your finished, like so:

placeholder 1 is: 2 pow 0 equals 1.

placeholder 2 is: 2 pow 1 equals 2.

placeholder 3 is: 2 pow 2 equals 4.

placeholder 4 is: 2 pow 3 equals 8.

placeholder 5 is: 2 pow 4 equals 16.

placeholder 6 is: 2 pow 5 equals 32.

placeholder 7 is: 2 pow 6 equals 64.

placeholder 8 is: 2 pow 7 equals 128.

Now we only add for the placeholders that have 1s.

128+16+8+2+1 = 155

What you will need:

A loop looping through indexes, and incrementing the exponent value as you go along, only adding the value if the index equals 1 in the binary number.

Hope my explanation makes sense. Good luck.